# How can I maintain a running total for multiple users across tables using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum, database-trigger

I am trying to build a simple website where user runs, inputs data and this is stored in “activity” table. There will be multiple users. Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT , username VARCHAR, password VARCHAR, total_distance INT);
```

and

`CREATE TABLE activity (id INT, user_id INT, distance INT, duration INT)`

The idea is to create a class with methods such as:

```
class Activity { public function viewMyActivity() {  } public function viewAllActivity() {  } public function showUsersRanking() {  } }
```

The "activity" table will keep growing as users add their activity data. I want to keep a running total for each user (updating "users" table with triggers?) so they can access it quicker, instead of querying the entire "activity" table every time a user wants their data or total users' data.

For example: user with id=5 runs 10km and this is added to their cumulative total in the total_distance column in users.

```
Table activity id=33 user_id=5 distance 10 duration 55
Table users id=5 username='foo' password='bar' total_distance=18 duration=130
```

As for time, I want users to separate using commas, e.g. 1,3 for 1 hour 30 minutes, then convert this somehow. There should be a simpler way, but more concerned about distance now.

I hope this is clearer.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: could you show tables and data, a trigger is the rigt approach, but without seeing your table structure it is hard to guess with the time

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend storing this information, which can be infered from the data that's already in the table. Maintaining derived information adds unnecessary complexity to your code.

Instead, you can use a view, that computes the information on the fly, and gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data:

```
create view user_view as
select 
    u.*, 
    coalesce(a.total_distance) total_distance, 
    coalesce(a.total_duration) total_duration
from users u
left join (
    select user_id, sum(distance) total_distance, sum(duration) total_duration
    from activity
    group by user_id
) a on a.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a view. A query will be just fine.